# flip a image in google slides using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I want to flip image using apps script. But its not flipping in place. I want to flip in place and not to move the image to a different location. I tried with

```
function myFunction() {
  var image = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getImages()[0]
  image.scaleWidth(-1)
}
```

**The image**

[image]

**The expected**

[image]

**Obtained result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the position a size:

```js
  const t = img.getTransform()
  img.setTransform(
    t.toBuilder()
      .setScaleX(-t.getScaleX())
      .setTranslateX(t.getTranslateX() + t.getScaleX() * img.getInherentWidth())
      .build()
  )
```

This flips the image by changing the matrix transform. Basically it's the scale and the move by the size of the image.

### References

- [Transformation matrix (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)
- [Class AffineTransform (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/affine-transform)
- [Class AffineTransformBuilder (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/affine-transform-builder)